# chef fill in xml values in template with hash in attribute

Tags: ruby, hash, chef-infra

I have an array of hashes with values in my attributes/default.rb file in chef like what I have below:

```
default['server']['database'] = [
    {
        'name' => 'srv1'
        'user' => 'usr1'
        'pass' => 'pwd1'
    },
    {
        'name' => 'srv2'
        'user' => 'user2'
        'pass' => 'pwd3'
    }
]
```

Then, I've got a templates/default/server.xml.erb file with the following nested loop:

```
<% node['server']['database'].each do |hash| %>
    <% hash.each do |key, value| %>
        <%if key == "name" %>
            <Resource name="#{value}"
                <% else %>
                    #{key}="#{value}"
                <% end %>
            <% end %>
            />
        <% end %>
```

The expected result is:

```
<Resource name="srv1"
    user="usr1"
    pass="pwd1"
/>
<Resource name="srv2"
    user="usr2"
    pass="pwd2"
/>
```

What I end up getting with this is:

```
<Resource name="#{value}"
    #{key}="#{value}"
    #{key}="#{value}"
/>
<Resource name="#{value}"
    #{key}="#{value}"
    #{key}="#{value}"
/>
```

I've tried this in plain ruby and got it to print expected results.  Not sure what I'm doing wrong here, but please, if you could shed some light I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use erb `<%= %>`

```
<% node['server']['database'].each do |hash| %>
    <% hash.each do |key, value| %>
        <%if key == "name" %>
            <Resource name="<%= value %>"
                <% else %>
                    <%= "#{key}=\"#{value}\"" %>
                <% end %>
            <% end %>
            />
        <% end %>
```

Comment: You can slightly simplify that, `<%= value %>` for example.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
<% node['server']['database'].each do |hash| %>
  <Resource name="<%= hash['name'] %>"
            user="<%= hash['user'] %>"
            pass="<%= hash['pass'] %>" />
<% end %>
```

Or:

```
<% node['server']['database'].each do |hash| %>
  <Resource <%= hash.map { |k, v| "#{k}=#{v.inspect}" }.join(' ') %> />
<% end %>
```

Please note that the order of keys in a hash can be difficult to debug in corner cases. In contrast to your nested example do my examples do not rely on a specific key ordering.

Comment: Ruby hash key ordering has been part of the language since the 1.9 days.

Comment: Ruby 1.9 grantees that the keys are returned in their *insertion order*, that is true. I wanted to point out that the OPs code is error prone, because it breaks as soon as the order is not like expected and that might happen by accident when someone changes the config, by updating the hash based on conditions, using an old Ruby version or because the hash might be read from an external file. On the other hand, my examples are easier to read, to understand and fault-tolerant.